# Kannel DLR report in MySQL

Tags: mysql, kannel

I have configured kannel in Ubuntu box. Sending SMS is working fine. 
Now my requirements are: to store the sent SMS and then update the sent status accordingly so that I can track any message status.

I searched a lot, tried creating db, tried various attempts to make php page that can insert into table but till time I am unable to achieve my task.

So here I am, asking if any one can provide some working example of:

- HTTP URL sample to input SMS along with DLR sample
- dlr-ul sample for `kannel.conf`
- db table sample
- PHP page that would be called to update the message status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing MO/MT/DLR in database you have to use SQLBOX between bearerbox and smsbox

```
<smsc>----<bearerbox>---<sqlbox>----<smsbox>
```

you can also insert MT sms in sqlbox table for sending sms , all sms are logged in sqlbox tables.

Example sqlbox.conf

```
group = sqlbox
id=sqlbox
smsbox-id=sqlbox-1
bearerbox-host=localhost
bearerbox-port=14002
smsbox-port=14003
sql-log-table=sent_sms
sql-insert-table=send_sms
log-file=/var/log/kannel/sqlbox.log
log-level=4

group = mysql-connection
id = sqlbox
host = localhost
username = root
password = 
database = sqlbox
max-connections = 1
```

bearerbox configuration kannel.conf, please change dlr-storage to database in production server

```
group = core
admin-port=13000
admin-password=admin
status-password=status
#black-list = "http://127.0.0.1/black/black-list.txt"
smsbox-port=14002
store-type=file
#store-type=spool
#store-file=/kannel-store.file
store-location=/kannel-store.file
access-log=/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.access
dlr-storage=internal
log-level=4
log-file=/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok after 10 days of hits and trial, Finally I made it as I wanted it to be  using Kannel/SQLBOX with triggers.

I made its short notes with examples on my blog , would be helpful for beginners :) Thanks

https://aacable.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/kannel-sms-gateway-delivery-reports-in-mysql-via-sqlbox/

https://aacable.wordpress.com/2016/09/07/sample-php-page-to-insert-data-into-kannelsqlbox/